# LINQ to XML handling duplicates

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-xml

I wrote method that loads values from xml file to `textBoxes`.

```
private void load(TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
     XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"test.xml");
     string nodeName = e.Node.Text;

     var data = from q in doc.Descendants("dog")
                where (string)q.Attribute("name") == nodeName
                select new Data
                {
                    name = q.Attribute("name").Value,
                    breed = q.Element("breed").Value,
                    sex = q.Element("sex").Value
                };


     foreach (var element in data)
     {
         textBox1.Text = element.name;
         textBox2.Text = element.breed;
         comboBox1.Text = element.sex;
     }
}
```

It works fine as long as I won't add another dog with the same `name` but different `breed`. My xml file looks like this:

```
<dogs>
<dog name="Mike">
<breed>dachshund</breed>
<sex>true</sex>
</dog>
<dog name="Mike">
<breed>husky</breed>
<sex>true</sex>
</dog>
</dogs>
```

When I'm trying load values from second node, nothing happens, since entry named `Mike` was found earlier. Tried using lists, but it didn't work (Or just I did something wrong). I want to allow that kind of "duplicates", only 1:1 duplicates are forriben (Already wrote this part and it works). If there would be way way to obtain `breed` in similiar way as I obtain `name`, it would solve the problem - just add another `where` in query.

```
private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
   nodeName = e.Node.Text;
}
```

That's how I'm getting `name` - by clicking on desired node in `treeView`. If there's more than one entry named the same, it only loads the latest. So my question is: how to deal with that? It's obvious that there can be dog named Tom, breed dachshud and dog named Tom, bread husky.

Comment: When you are assigning value to textbox in a loop, then you will have only last value assigned. What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, you're right, that's my problem. I want to be able to load specific node, but for now if there are two nodes with the same `name`, it load the last one no matter what. As @Jean-Bernard Pellerin I can use another property, tag.

Comment: Is it winforms or web application?

Comment: I forgot to mention this, it's winforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.tag.aspx) property instead of the `Text` one.

You'd have to modify how you're populating your tree, but you can assign a specific object or value to `Node.Tag` and then retrieve it later. This can contain an id or potentially all the information about the given dog. Then in your `treeView1_NodeMouseClick` method, the `TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e` will contain much more information than just the displayed text.